# How to download all variables from several databases with one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I have several tables in which a shared variable is stored.
How to get all variables from each table with one query?
And how to return all variables as in the example?
Is it even possible?

```
$id1 = BDR::selectBySQL("g","SELECT * FROM i1 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1");
foreach($id1 as $id1) 
{
    $id1 = $id1['idz'];

}
$id2 = BDR::selectBySQL("g","SELECT * FROM i2 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1");
foreach($id2 as $id2) 
{
    $id2 = $id2['idxc'];

}
$id3 = BDR::selectBySQL("g","SELECT * FROM i3 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1");
foreach($id3 as $id3) 
{
    $id3 = $id3['idsd'];

}
return ['id2'=>$id1,'id2'=>$id2,'id3'=>$id3];
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table have the same schema (same of columnd and corresponding data type) you could use a `select union  all`

```
  SELECT * FROM i1 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1 
  union all  
  SELECT * FROM i2 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1
  union all 
  SELECT * FROM i3 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1
```

In this way you should retrieve a list of rows  .. with the desired  result and iterating over the result you could obation all the values  you need

```
$idAll = BDR::selectBySQL("g",
    "SELECT * FROM i1 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1 
      union all  
      SELECT * FROM i2 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1
      union all 
      SELECT * FROM i3 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1 ");

foreach($idAll as $row) 
{
    $id[] = $row['idz'];

}

return $id;
```

you can check the content of $id Array using  `var_dump($id);`

and last if the tables comes form different database on same server you can use an explictit table name eg:  `db1.i1`

Comment: what to do next, how to enter variables into a function and return

Comment: what to do next, how to enter variables into a function and return?

Comment: but I see that I need to add a separate query to each database

Comment: I was thinking about something like that `SELECT * FROM i1,i2,i3 WHERE ix='".$this->ixx."' LIMIT 1`

Comment: your last comment seems not the best choice for your problem . in your case the select union is the best way .